# Save a CoreData object in a specific NSPersistentStore

Tags: core-data

I've the following problem:

I have two or more persistent stores. And I have created an entity in the xcdatamodel named "House". Now I have these two files for the NSManagedObject House.

Now I want to know how do I save an instance of the entity house in a specific persistent store?

So I tried to work with `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForName:@"House" inManagedObjectContext:context]` and `[context assignObject: toPersistentStore:]`. But it didn't worked until now. Am I on the right way to do it?

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Answering my own question:

The problem was that I allocated a completely new persistentStoreCoordinate who coordinates all the stores. So the coordinator wasn't linked to the managedObjectContext.

Could be solved with

__persistentStoreCoordinator = [__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];

Comment: Move this comment to an answer and mark it checked. You are allowed to answer your own questions after 24 hours. The system will show this question as unanswered if you leave it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The problem was that I allocated a completely new persistentStoreCoordinate who coordinates all the stores. So the coordinator wasn't linked to the managedObjectContext.

Could be solved with

`__persistentStoreCoordinator = [__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];`